# Where are environment variables specified when .profile, .bash_login, .bash_profile cannot be found?

Tags: snow-leopard, bash

When I type env at the terminal prompt, I get a dump of all the environment variables.  When I check / or ~, however, I do not see a .profile, .bash_login or .bash_profile.

Where is this being stored in Mac OS X 10.6.7 ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you are using bash.

bash first runs /etc/profile. /etc/profile (on Mac OS X 10.6.7) runs path_helper(8) which is where your default paths get set. After that it runs /etc/bashrc which doesn't do much. Once the default configuration is set, it moves on to the user login scripts.

bash looks in your home directory for .bash_profile, .bash_login, and .profile in that order. bash will run the first of these that it finds and stop looking.

Comment: Also, some variables come from *launchd* (e.g. TMPDIR, SHELL, HOME, USER, LOGNAME, SSH_AUTH_SOCK, DISPLAY, Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render), *Terminal* (e.g. TERM, TERM_PROGRAM, TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION, COMMAND_MODE) and *bash* itself (PWD, SHLVL).

Comment: Thanks Chris!  Out of curiosity - why are some of the variables associated with launchd ?  The other ones make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Usually those files should reside in your /etc directory. In case when you don't have your local copy of say .profile then the system uses /etc/profile .

Comment: Thanks Tigran!  That was interesting - I had searched for .profile, but I see that it is profile, as you have noted.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following links. Some of them may help. ;)

1. https://superuser.com/questions/182402/setting-environment-variables-mac-10-6
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x
3. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1067/_index.html

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, the .plist file is not found on my system.  Any reason that you can think of ?  I'm running 10.6.7.

Comment: Please explain something in the text and give information what the links are - as I assume blank links etc are to virus, phishing etc

Comment: @Mark - A good point.  In this case, the links are safe.

Comment: When the comment was written - the text just read link not the URI as it is now

Comment: Well, after @Marks comment I have edited the links to make it more transparent.