# What is the difference between .bash_profile and .bashrc?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

To make an alias for the Terminal in OS X, you can either put the aliases in `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`. What is the difference between the two and why would I choose to put aliases in one and not the other?

Comment: Not to discourage the unix knowledge here, but bash is a pure UNIX beast so you might get better knowledge or have this question answered several times over on a partner site. There are well over 200 bashrc question/answer pairs over on [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?page=5&tab=relevance&q=%5bbash%5d%20profile%20bashrc)

Comment: There is .profile as well... See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751252/difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile-on-snow-leopard) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you `brew install bash` and use iTerm2, you could set `profile -> command` to `/usr/local/bin/bash` which will load `.bashrc` by default after `.bash_profile`. This also gives you Bash 4 goodies...

Comment: If you are here wondering why the terminal is not sourcing `.bash_profile`, that is because with macOS Catalina switched from `bash` to `zsh`; therefore now you have to use `.zprofile` instead of `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 434, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is executed for login shells, while `.bashrc` is executed for interactive non-login shells.

When you login (type username and password) via console, either sitting at the machine, or remotely via ssh: `.bash_profile` is executed to configure your shell before the initial command prompt.

But, if you’ve already logged into your machine and open a new terminal window (xterm) then `.bashrc` is executed before the window command prompt. `.bashrc` is also run when you start a new bash instance by typing `/bin/bash` in a terminal.

On OS X, Terminal by default runs a login shell every time, so this is a little different to most other systems, but you can configure that in the preferences.

Comment: `On OS X, Terminal by default runs a login shell every time` - I have always been so confused by not realizing this. Great info!

Comment: I'm on OS X and I use zshell instead of bash, and iTerm instead of Terminal. Despite the fact that I'm using a different terminal and a different shell than the answer discusses, OS X still seems to be considering everything a login shell, because `.zprofile` gets ran every time.

Comment: For those looking for a thorough explanation of the combinations of login/non-login and interactive/non-interactive shells and when they run these config files, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/38715

Comment: This is a really good answer. It helped me understand why I always need to do a manual step after installing RVM on Ubuntu or Fedora to get it to work, where I cut and paste the line `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*` from `~/.bash_profile` to `~/.bashrc`. RVM seems to install itself as if it were always being installed on a Mac. It assumes that every time a terminal is started, it will be a login shell. If you use your computer differently, where you only log in once, you need to tweak things.

Comment: It should be noted, that a new Terminal.app window or tab will look for and source `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` as mentioned, but if you spawn a new bash using something like `exec bash` or `bash` from that the new window/tab, it will only seek and source `~/.bashrc`. To avoid that, use `exec bash -l` or `bash -l` to spawn the new bash as a 'login' shell, which will then look for `.bash_profile/.profile`. Same for new windows created within tmux/screen, they will only source `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 77):

X11 will look at your `.bashrc` while a "regular" Terminal will look at `.bash_profile`

However, if you add the following to your `.bash_profile`, you can then move everything into your `.bashrc` file so as to consolidate everything into one place instead of two:

```
if [ -f $HOME/.bashrc ]; then
        source $HOME/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: Or you could just do `cd ~ ; ln -s .bashrc .bash_profile`.

Comment: These 2 configuration files have a clearly separate function. In some cases, it is necessary to have things to initialize at the beginning of session and only there (`~/.bash_profile`). It is also often necessary to have things to define incrementaly at every shell level (`~/.bashrc`). It isn't the best idea to suggest to suppress this freedom.

Comment: @danielAzuelos: Lurch left this part out, but the OS X Terminal sources `~/.bash_profile` for every new window/tab, so there's not really a way to separate the two as far as Terminal is concerned.

Comment: @mipadi There is still value to separate them. For example, `.bash_profile` can never be sourced again in child process. Every level of nested Bash sources `.bashrc`, so if you put something like `export A=a:$A` in `.bashrc`, your `$A` will get longer in nested Bash. I typically leave environment variable in profile, and aliases in RC.

Comment: @FranklinYu May not be that big of a deal for many people, but I totally agree! It is a great technical point to remind people and deserves way more upvotes.

Comment: i saw something like  <. ~/.bashrc >rather than< source ~/.bashrc>, is there any difference?

Comment: @DingxinXu the dot in front of a file path (like `. ~/.bashrc`) is a shortcut to [`source`](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html), so no difference. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/whats-the-meaning-of-a-dot-before-a-command-in-shell

Comment: One issue with this. When you run `source .bashrc` in Terminal having `if [ -f $HOME/.bashrc ]; then
        source $HOME/.bashrc
fi` in `.bash_profile` duplicates whatever paths you have added in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 32):

For macOS, the code to put into `.bash_profile` to consolidate everything into `.bashrc` is the following:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

This is more specific for Mac terminal user.

Comment: While true, how is this different from [Lurch's answer from 2012](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc/51043#51043)?

Answer (score 13):

TLDR; use `.bash_profile` for your aliases.

The way the different initialisation files work together is a bit more complicated, and there are some important special cases in OSX. Here are the highlights:

- Bash, on any platform, executes one of several different files depending on how it is invoked. The details are [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html).
- OSX's Terminal App does something non-standard: it creates every new tab or window as if it were a login shell, which means that `.bash_profile` is called. Thus the TLDR advice above.
- `.bashrc` is also an option, but that will be called every time you create a subshell (i.e., invoke `bash`), which can create inefficiency if you update a variable within it (e.g., `PATH=/bin/foo:$PATH`)
- Other apps that have embedded terminals can choose to follow Terminal App's convention or not. Notably, [Visual Studio Code, by default, does not](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/20265#issuecomment-278818467).
- Apps invoked via the GUI are not spawned from a shell. Thus, there are several competing mechanisms for setting environment variables for them to see, which have [changed over the years](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/14652/237097).
- Snippets that call `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile` are quite common.

Comment: Why exactly is using `.bash_profile` for aliases complicated? The items you list only partially are about aliases at all, so instead of just listing some bullets which might explain *why* it seems to be complicated can you maybe propose a way to make it easier within these constraints?

Comment: I see your point. It is not that using .bash_profile is complicated. It is that the way the files is invoked is complicated. I'll update.

Comment: Calling .bashrc from .bash_profile is recommended in the GNU bash manual - otherwise how do you set variables etc that you need both in login shells and non intereactive ones?

Comment: Every terminal emulator that I use on different OS's has an option to run new windows as a login shell, xterm and Xfce to name just two.

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu/debain I add this code at the end of `.bashrc`:

```
 if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
    source ~/.bash_profile
 fi
```

Now my aliases take effect in all new opened terminals(or tabs)