# Can homebrew and RVM agree on a $PATH?

Tags: macos, homebrew, path

I'm trying to install [Yeoman.io](https://yeoman.io/) and part of it requires [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to be installed. I am on Mountain Lion (10.8) and things seemed to install correctly except when I run `$ homebrew doctor` it complains with the following message:

```
Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your path.
Consider amending your PATH variable so it contains:
/usr/local/sbin
```

Here is what my **~/.bashrc** looks like:

```
#PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
setenv PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$PATH
```

and my **.bash_profile** looks like:

```
[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

I use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) so it's written in its own stuff in case that affects the homebrew installation.

Comment: Can we assume $PATH does actually contain /usr/local/sbin and when you reboot and open a new terminal window?

Comment: when I run `echo $PATH` I get the following output:     `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/fazal/.rvm/bin`

Comment: Last question about e question? Did you choose a shell other than bash (the default shell on OS X?)

Comment: I'm using the standard shell via terminal.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities?lq=1 for another way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path (as shown) doesn't contain `/usr/local/sbin`. Add that in the line where you set the path. Also, bash doesn't use `setenv`; just use `PATH=...`.

Comment: I've edited **~/.bashsrc** to look like:     `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:$HOME/.rvm/bin` however when I do `echo $PATH` it returns this:     `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/fazal/.rvm/bin` is there some sort of caching issue going on?

Comment: Did you quit the shell after making the changes? Also, you may want to make these changes in ~/.bash_profile too (if you use Terminal)

Comment: (Can't edit my previous comment). See this for the difference between bash_profile and bashrc: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc

Comment: I edited **~/.bash_profile** and restarted, finally it all seems to be working. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The OS X Terminal loads ~/.bash_profile instead of ~/.bashrc.

So it is common (and even recommended) to put your customizations into ~/.bash_profile and then source it from ~/.bashrc with:

```
[ -n "$PS1" ] && source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Future Googlers, what if you've already amended your .bash_profile and one change or another makes either brew or rvm mad?

.bash_profile for a happy rvm.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

.bash_profile for a happy homebrew.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Open up your /etc/paths in your editor so that usr/local/bin is in the top slot here's mine

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

And then use the $PATH which makes RVM happy.