# Automator fail with ffmpeg bash line

Tags: bash, automator

- I want to batch convert .m4a music from iTunes to a flash drive as .mp3
- This bash script... (source https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1614765)

  ```
  for f in *.m4a; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 256k "${f%.m4a}.mp3"; done
  ```

...achieves this, but I'll like use set up an Automator Folder Action to do this for me.

AFAIK, the automator in this screen shot *should* work but does not.

I'd read some stuff - which I didn't really understand - about "$f" needing to be in quotes, but it already is.

[image]

Any advice, please?

Comment: You never said how it failed.  "It does not work" is pretty vague.

Comment: Thank you - the folder action just doesn't do anything. Nothing happens. The .m4a file gets dropped into the folder and no magic conversion happens. There's no error message or anything.

Answer (score 3):

Automator supplies arguments (file names) to the shell script.
Try:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    case $f in
        *.m4a)
             /absolute/path/to/ffmpeg -i "$f" -acodec libmp3lame -ab 256k "${f%.m4a}.mp3"
             ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I think the path to ffmpeg is the key. It probably can't find it since it is not in the users path or environment. I have had similar problems with bash scripts on Automator.

Comment: Ok- so Terminal knows to look in the right place for ffmpeg (i.e., /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg) but Automator needs to be told? I'd used your suggestion and replaced the path with /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg but I only get the same symptoms (no response from the Folder and with the Application: 'ffmpeg: command not found'.

Comment: Yes, this answer and @ArchonOSX are correct.  The shell that is opened is a non-interactive, non-login shell meaning it doesn't process the same files (`.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`)  See [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc) for more explanation but suffice to say, if your path isn't set in both places or `.bashrc` doesn't source `.bash_profile`, it doesn't know about your path.