# How to change the default VNC client?

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a VNC Viewer installed. Is it possible to make it the default VNC client?

I would like to get rid of the built-in Screen Sharing app and automatically open VNC Viewer whenever I type

```
open vnc://server:port
```

in Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Try the RCDefaultApp preference pane at http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/. It lets you choose the application to be launched for all sorts of situations.

Install it, open it (it becomes the "Default Apps" preference pane), and then choose the "URLs" tab:

[image]

Scroll down to the "vnc" prefix, and then choose what you like from the "Default Application" popup.

Answer (score 1):

You could unload the screensharing service (and thus remove the need to install software):

`sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist`

and start it again by:

`sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.screensharing.plist`

Alternatively, you could create an alias (a custom command) by adding a line into your `.bashrc` file (an explanation of the difference between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` on OSX is here: [What is the difference between .bash_profile and .bashrc?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51036/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc))

The alias line may look like:

`alias myvnc='vncviewer server:port'` (whatever the executable and paramter required to start the program)

Save `.bashrc` and exit. Then type `source ~/.bashrc` in the terminal to reload the file to test your new alias. In this case, typing `myvnc` will trigger the command you have entered between the two quotes.

This can be used for anything to start things quickly via terminal with your own preferences.